# alphabetical order in Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, for-loop

Okay I have questions regarding the following code:

```
s = "wxyabcd"

myString = s[0]
longest = s[0]
for i in range(1, len(s)):
    if s[i] >= myString[-1]:
        myString += s[i]
        if len(myString) > len(longest):
            longest = myString
    else:
        myString = s[i]
print longest
```

Answer: "abcd"
w
wx
wxy
a
ab
abc
abcd

I am new to Python and I am trying to learn how some of these loops work but I am very confused. This found what the longest string in alphabetical order was... The actual answer was "abcd" but I know that the process it went through was one by one.

Question: Can someone please guide me through the code so I can understand it better? Since there are 7 characters I am assuming it starts by saying: "For each item in range 1-7 if the item is 'more' than myString [-1] which is 'w' then I add the letter plus the item in i which in this case it would be 'x'.

I get lost right after this... So from a - z : a > z? Is that how it is? And how then when s[i] != myString[-1] did it skip to start from 'a' in s[i].

Sorry I am all over the place. Anyways i've tried to search places online to help me learn this but some things are just hard. I know that in a few months ill get the hang of it and hopefully be more fluent.

Thank you!

Comment: Your formatting is borked - add some spaces so we can be sure we know what we're looking at.

Comment: It usually helps to just fill in print statements where you're unsure what happened. Just print out the values of the variables you're unsure of, to see what happened. For example you could try to add two print statements at the start of the for loop. for myString and longest.

Comment: Python is not a C language. If you ever find yourself typing `range(0, len(some_string)`, take a step back and think about what you're doing.  Instead of s[i] you want `for si in s:` then just use the variable `si` wherever you would have used `s[i]` before (but please rename it something more descriptive).

Comment: @nemec that's not true in this case (necessarily). He could use an accumulator that grabs the individual letters, but it seems easier to me to remember indexes and use string slicing on those indexes.

Comment: @adsmith, unless you *need* to use `i` for something (and OP doesn't), it's much less confusing to not add another variable to the code. You could rewrite it in such a way that needing an index is necessary, sure, but even then use `for i, si in enumerate(s):` so that "`s[i]`" is only calculated once.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of an explanation of the control flow and what's going on with Python's indexing, hope it helps:

```
s = "wxyabcd"

myString = s[0] # 'w'
longest = s[0] # 'w' again, for collecting other chars
for i in range(1, len(s)): # from 1 to 7, exclusive of 7, so 2nd index to last
    if s[i] >= myString[-1]: # compare the chars, e.g. z > a, so x and y => True
        myString += s[i] # concatenate on to 'w'
        if len(myString) > len(longest): # evident?
            longest = myString # reassign longest to myString
    else:
        myString = s[i] # reassign myString to where you are in s.
print longest
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# s is a 7 character string
s = "wxyabcd"

# set `mystring` to be the first character of s, 'w'
myString = s[0]

# set `longest` to be the first character of s, 'w'
longest = s[0]

# loop from 1 up to and not including length of s (7)
# Which equals for i in (1,2,3,4,5,6):
for i in range(1, len(s)):

    # Compare the character at i with the last character of `mystring`
    if s[i] >= myString[-1]:

        # If it is greater (in alphabetical sense)
        # append the character at i to `mystring`
        myString += s[i]

        # If this makes `mystring` longer than the previous `longest`,
        # set `mystring` to be the new `longest`
        if len(myString) > len(longest):
            longest = myString

    # Otherwise set `mystring` to be a single character string
    # and start checking from index i
    else:
        myString = s[i]

# `longest` will be the longest `mystring` that was formed,
# using only characters in descending alphabetic order
print longest
```

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches I can think of (quickly)

```
def approach_one(text): # I approve of this method!
    all_substrings = list()
    this_substring = ""
    for letter in text:
        if len(this_substring) == 0 or letter > this_substring[-1]:
            this_substring+=letter
        else:
            all_substrings.append(this_substring)
            this_substring = letter
    all_substrings.append(this_substring)
    return max(all_substrings,key=len)

def approach_two(text):
    #forthcoming
```